# Is there any way to keep status bar (iOS 7) but hide the signal?

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I try to solve same cosmetic issue.
I'm set custom navigation controller with picture in it.
The status bar clock Exceeds that. 
I didn't find any answers for that.
Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your image instead because you can't keep the status bar and hide the clock. Or even better get rid of the status bar.

```
-(BOOL)preferStatusBarHidden {

return YES;

}
```